# Extract specific pattern from data on R

Tags: regex, r, text-mining

I have a ".txt" file which came with a lot of juridics text but I only want to extract the dates to make a further analysis and graphics. Here is an example (sorry its in Portuguese):

> "AR - 4024-03.2010.5.00.0000(2)" "ACORDAM os Ministros da Egrégia
>   Subseção II Especializada em Dissídios Individuais do Tribunal
>   Superior do Trabalho, por unanimidade, não conhecer do recurso
>   ordinário, por incabível. **Brasília, 24 de maio de 2011**. Firmado por
>   assinatura digital (MP 2.200-2/2001) Alberto Luiz Bresciani de Fontan
>   Pereira Ministro Relator fls. PROCESSO Nº
>   TST-AR-4024-03.2010.5.00.0000 Firmado por assinatura digital em
>   26/05/2011 pelo sistema AssineJus da Justiça do Trabalho, conforme MP
>   2.200-2/2001, que instituiu a Infra-Estrutura de Chaves Públicas Brasileira."

That file has a lot of those things but I want to extract only the highlighted parts and put them in a separate vector. I've been trying match, grep nothing is working. Perhaps because I'm new to R.

Comment: When you say "grep nothing is working"...what have you tried? Also, how are you reading this file into R?

Comment: You need to think carefully about the positions within the strings that the dates come in, the various patterns and arrangements that they come in, and tailor your regex to your application.  If you want advice on crafting some code, give more examples of the form that a date could be in.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will match dates of the form that you have highlighted:

```
"\\d{1,2} de (janeiro|fevereiro|março|abril|maio|junho|julho|agosto|septembro|outubro|novembro|dezembro) de \\d{4}"
```

See `?regex` for details on special characters and quantifiers. You can substitute on the items that match:

```
your_text <-  c("AR - 4024-03.2010.5.00.0000", "ACORDAM os Ministros da Egrégia Subseção II Especializada em Dissídios Individuais do Tribunal Superior do Trabalho, por unanimidade, não conhecer do recurso ordinário, por incabível. Brasília, 24 de maio de 2011. Firmado por assinatura digital (MP 2.200-2/2001) Alberto Luiz Bresciani de Fontan Pereira Ministro Relator fls. PROCESSO Nº TST-AR-4024-03.2010.5.00.0000 Firmado por assinatura digital em 26/05/2011 pelo sistema AssineJus da Justiça do Trabalho, conforme MP 2.200-2/2001, que instituiu a Infra-Estrutura de Chaves Públicas Brasileira.")

sub( "(.+ )(\\d{1,2} de (janeiro|fevereiro|março|abril|maio|junho|julho|agosto|septembro|outubro|novembro|dezembro) de \\d{4})(.+)", "\\2", your_text[grepl("\\d{1,2} de (janeiro|fevereiro|março|abril|maio|junho|julho|agosto|septembro|outubro|novembro|dezembro) de \\d{4}", your_text )
[1] "AR - 4024-03.2010.5.00.0000" "24 de maio de 2011"
```

To remove the non-date-containing items, you can use `grepl` to preselect:

```
> sub( "(.+ )(\\d{1,2} de (janeiro|fevereiro|março|abril|maio|junho|julho|agosto|septembro|outubro|novembro|dezembro) de \\d{4})(.+)", "\\2", your_text[grepl("\\d{1,2} de (janeiro|fevereiro|março|abril|maio|junho|julho|agosto|septembro|outubro|novembro|dezembro) de \\d{4}", your_text )])
[1] "24 de maio de 2011"
```

If you need to play with the patterns to get the hang of using capture-classes, there are nifty regex testing webpages.

Comment: It worked quite well. I found that the main problem were at my archive reading. About the regular expression it can be simplier but you gave me a light.
`library(stringr)

dates = str_extract_all(text, "(\\d+ de (janeiro|fevereiro|março|abril|maio|junho|julho|agosto|setembro|outubro|novembro|dezembro) de \\d+)")`

Comment: It's possible that you may have the months as a vector that you could paste with sep="|" in your locale as the `month.abb` or `month.name`-objects. I believe that object gets "internationalized". If they need to be "upper-" or "lower-cased there are `tolower` and `toupper` functions.